# Jquery nested list collapsing

Tags: jquery, html, list, slidetoggle

I have problem with collapsing list using jquery:-

**html file**

```
<ul>
  <li class="dir">subject1
      <ul>
          <li class="dir">lab1
              <ul>
                  <li>lab1.pdf</li>
              </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="dir">lab2
              <ul>
                  <li>lab2.pdf</li>
              </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="dir">lab3
              <ul>
                  <li>lab3.pdf</li>
              </ul>
          </li>
      </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="dir">subject2
      <ul>
          <li class="dir">lab1
              <ul>
                  <li>lab1.pdf</li>
              </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="dir">lab2
              <ul>
                  <li>lab2.pdf</li>
              </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="dir">lab3
              <ul>
                  <li>lab3.pdf</li>
              </ul>
          </li>
      </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="dir">subject3
      <ul>
          <li class="dir">lab1
              <ul>
                  <li>lab1.pdf</li>
              </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="dir">lab2
              <ul>
                  <li>lab2.pdf</li>
              </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="dir">lab3
              <ul>
                  <li>lab3.pdf</li>
              </ul>
          </li>
      </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**script**

```
$('.dir').click(function() {
    $(this).children().slideToggle();
});
```

`li` tags with `dir` class are folders and I want only them to collapse when clicked on them.
And now I get that every dir is collapsing even if I use `$this`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `stopPropagation` property.

```
$('.dir').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).children().slideToggle();
});
```

```js
$('.dir').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).children().slideToggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="dir">subject1
      <ul>
          <li class="dir">lab1
              <ul>
                  <li>lab1.pdf</li>
              </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="dir">lab2
              <ul>
                  <li>lab2.pdf</li>
              </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="dir">lab3
              <ul>
                  <li>lab3.pdf</li>
              </ul>
          </li>
      </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="dir">subject2
      <ul>
          <li class="dir">lab1
              <ul>
                  <li>lab1.pdf</li>
              </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="dir">lab2
              <ul>
                  <li>lab2.pdf</li>
              </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="dir">lab3
              <ul>
                  <li>lab3.pdf</li>
              </ul>
          </li>
      </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="dir">subject3
      <ul>
          <li class="dir">lab1
              <ul>
                  <li>lab1.pdf</li>
              </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="dir">lab2
              <ul>
                  <li>lab2.pdf</li>
              </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="dir">lab3
              <ul>
                  <li>lab3.pdf</li>
              </ul>
          </li>
      </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: works perfectly, didn't knew that this can be accomplished so flawlesly, you saved my day!

Comment: @dmnmlk, Don't forget to accept and vote my answer to help other people.

Comment: could You help me with one glich? when you slideUp all the lab1, lab2 and lab3 folders and then click on parent folder(for example subject 1) there is a problem because lab1-lab3 folders are sliding down and parent folder is silding up. my jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/VNkM2/1660/

Comment: Use `.children()` like in my post.

Comment: oh i misread your answer and didn't noticed that, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

if you wrap your outest `ul` with `div` you can do

```
$('div>ul>li .dir').click(function() {
    $(this).slideToggle();
});
```

Comment: sorry, I edited your answer instead my answer. Can you reject ?

Comment: okay, but i want every `li` with class `dir` collapsing in different levels on list

Comment: @dmnmlk see my original answer